# Passing parameters from Logic app to CosmosDB stored procedure with parameterized sql query

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps, prepared-statement

I am trying to call a stored procedure in CosmosDB from Logic App with some parameters to be able to retrive the number of documents that meet the query requirements.

Example of query I want to do:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.Time_Stamp BETWEEN time1 AND time2
```

I have tried to test my stored procedure in Data Explorer. this what I was doing.

```
// SAMPLE STORED PROCEDURE
function sample(input) {
var context = getContext();
var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var response = context.getResponse();
//var inputtf = JSON.parse(input).id;
var filterQuery = "SELECT * FROM c where c.id = "+ input ;
console.log(filterQuery);
// Query documents and take 1st item.
var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
    collection.getSelfLink(),
    filterQuery,
function (err, feed, options) {
    if (err) throw err;
response.setBody(JSON.stringify(feed));
});
if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

**As an input I was giving:**

[image]

I get this an a result :

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.id = 220
```

So I can see that my query is able to get parameters in it.

The thing is I get no results for that query (Result is "[]")

This is my document I am trying to query:

[image]

This would be the kind of payload I would sent to the stored procedure to begin with. Next step would be to add a start time and end time parameters in UTC.

[image]

As an end goal, I would like to get in Logic App, in the output, a count of how many documents were meeting the query requirement.

Comment: The `id` is a string not an integer. Do you get results for `SELECT * FROM c where c.id = '220'`?

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith, it did tried to put as an input '220' so the query look like "SELECT * FROM c where c.id = '220'", but I still get [] as a result.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, the partition key parameter for the execute store procedure activity should be sent as string. So, you need to add quotes between your partition key value.

In your case: "42976" instead of 42976

The stored procedures need a valid partition key value to be executed and to response the query. You can see a note in the top of this page from Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs?tabs=javascript